# Username didn't change properly

Tags: windows

I've chaned my username (with admin privileges) using [this method](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/3-ways-to-change-user-account-name-in-windows-10.html), name has changed but in C:/Users there is still the same folder with the old name. How can I change this folder name?

I'm using windows 10 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected behaviour: changing the username won't change the `ProfileImagePath`. Renaming the profile directory isn't necessary, and causes problems if there are open handles under the directory. But it's still possible. Assuming you have already changed the username:

1. Log in as another administrator. Make sure the user is logged out!
2. Rename the folder `C:\Users\oldusername` to `C:\Users\newusername`.
3. Get the SID for the user: `wmic useraccount where name="newusername" get sid`
4. Open the Registry Editor `regedit` and go to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<SID>
   ```
5. Change value of `ProfileImagePath` (`REG_EXPAND_SZ`) to `C:\Users\newusername`.
6. Restart the computer.

There might still be some problems, if some programs references to some files or directories using absolute paths, so I wouldn't recommend doing this unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Would it be easier&safer to create another user with administrator priviliges and use it as I use my own now (so it will have different folder name as a consequence)?

Comment: If the goal is to have another account with another name, then yes.